# Does contener have a meaning I'm not familiar with?

Tags: traducción

Someone asked me, "que contiene el nombre Xxxx en ingles?".  I thought "contener" was pretty much the same as "to contain" in English, and online dictionaries seem to agree. Is there some other meaning, or us this some idiom I'm not familiar with?

UPDATE
Sorry, there's not really any context. It was a question asked in the chat for a cell phone game.  If no one else knows more about this, maybe they just made a typo. It's an unusual name, so they probably meant to ask what it meant, but that doesn't seem to be what they typed.

Comment: Can you provide some additional context? It's hard to know what might have been meant.

Comment: I don't understand the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R.A.E definition of 'contener' is, among others,

1. tr. Dicho de una cosa: Llevar o encerrar dentro de sí a otra. U. t. c. prnl.

which roughly translates to: to have something inside something else.

So, if I had to make an educated guess, I'd say he's asking about some connotation or secret meaning the word has.  To be honest, it's not something you'd probably say here in Spain (don't know if it might be a normal expression in latin american countries)

Comment: +1 I'm from Mexico, and it doesn't seem like something we'd say either...